# Call function on a single page

Tags: categories, exclude

How can I apply this function to a single page ID:

```
function exclude_jobs_locations($args){
    $exclude = "40";
    $args["exclude"] = $exclude;
    return $args;
}
add_filter("sjb_job_location_filter_args","exclude_jobs_locations");
```

Can I also exclude child categories when parent category is excluded?

I've tried with:

```
function exclude_jobs_locations_uk($args){  
if( is_page( 2094 ) ) {
    $exclude = "40";
    $args["exclude"] = $exclude;
}
return $args;
}
 add_filter("sjb_job_location_filter_args","exclude_jobs_locations_uk");
```

But something goes wrong.

I use this function to exclude category from:

```
// Creating list on non-empty job location                    
$jobloc_select = wp_dropdown_categories(apply_filters('sjb_job_location_filter_args', array(
                    'show_option_none' => __('Location', 'simple-job-board'),
                    'hide_empty'       => 0,
                    'name'             => 'selected_location',
                    'orderby'          => 'NAME',
                    'order'            => 'ASC',
                    'class'            => 'sjb-form-control',
                    'hierarchical'     => TRUE,
                    'value_field'      => 'slug',
                    'taxonomy'         => 'jobpost_location',                        
                    'selected'         => $selected_location,
                    'echo'             => FALSE,
                )));
                ?>
```

Comment: What is `sjb_job_location_filter_args`? That appears to be specific to some plugin. Note that 3rd-party plugin support is off-topic here.

Comment: yes, i must hook that function

Comment: we don't know what it is or when it runs, how can we answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your function runs generally, to limit it to a specific page use

```
if( is_page( 2094 ) ) {
    add_filter("sjb_job_location_filter_args","exclude_jobs_locations_uk");
}
```

The location of the function definition doesn't matter.

P.S. Regarding excluding categories . . . yeah, we'd need to know a lot more about what's going on with the called (plugin?) function

Comment: no, not working like that.

Comment: We need a lot more information to help. Before limiting your function to a specific page ,does it work? What does it do? Where's that code, default $args, etc.

Help me help you.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to make a template:

```
if (!is_page_template('jobs-uk.php'))
add_filter('sjb_job_location_filter_args', 'exclude_jobs_locations_uk');
```